# jquery AJAX requests not updating php variable

Tags: php, jquery

I have a comics website, [Hitting Trees with Sticks](http://HittingTreesWithSticks.com), that allows a user to get next, previous, or random comic id by pressing next or simply pressing arrow keys.

Since images are stored in a database, the only way for me cycle through these images on the client side was to store them in a javascript array, and store the php $imgid in a javascript variable as imgIndex. Then I could alter that index on the client side when they press keyboard keys.

When the user presses a key, I'm using pushstate to alter the imgid in the URL, but that's not actually updating the server side $imgid. I need to update the server side $imgid because I'm associating a liking function with each specific ID... but currently, the total likes associated with an img ID won't refresh/update when I press a key to get a new image.

My solution was to not only use the PushState to update the URL, but when a key is pressed, I use a $.post, and send the updated imgIndex to the php script.

**Here are snippets:**

**KeyInput.php**: This is the client-side javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var imgArray = [<?php echo implode(',', getImages($site)) ?>];
  var imgIndex = <?php echo $imgid ?>;

$(document).ready(function() {      
    var img = document.getElementById("showimg");
    img.src = imgArray[<?php echo $imgid ?>];

    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
        var key = e.which;
        var rightarrow = 39;
        var leftarrow = 37;
        var random = 82;

        if (key == rightarrow) 
        {
            imgIndex++;
            if (imgIndex > imgArray.length-1) 
            {
                imgIndex = 0;
            }
            img.src = imgArray[imgIndex];
            window.history.pushState(null, null, '.?action=viewimage&site=comics&id=' + imgIndex);

            $.post('./templates/viewimage.php', { _newImgId : imgIndex },
                function(data) {
                    //alert(data);
                }
            );

        }
```

**viewimage.php** This is the file that originally gets the $imgid, then it calls the keyInput.php script to accept key input... that alters the javascript imgid. For testing purposes, I've tried using $.post and $.get AJAX to send the updated imgid, as you can see below, that's `$newID = $_POST['_newImgId];`. When I echo out $newID, it says it's not defined.

```
<?php 
/*
Controls display of comic on the viewComic template
*/
include 'include/header.php';

global $site, $imgid;

$cat = (isset($_GET['cat']) ? ($_GET['cat']) : null); 
$site = (isset($_GET['site']) ? ($_GET['site']) : null);
$title = (isset($_GET['title']) ? ($_GET['title']) : null);
$imgid = $_GET['id']; 

include './scripts/keyinput.php'; 

$newID = $_POST['_newImgId];
echo $newID; //THIS SHOULD ECHO THE UPDATED ID, but it says it is not defined
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you mentioned it, but you are aware of the mixing in HTTP Request methods in your example, right?. By that I mean, the JS code is calling a POST with "_postID" and your PHP Example is using $_GET["_getID"].

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `$_post['_postID']` since your javascript uses post?

Comment: @WebDeskIL Yes it was a typo

Comment: I can see that you fixed it, but why are you using `$_POST['_getID']` instead of `$_post['_postID']` when your javascript query uses `_postID`?

Comment: @WebDeskIL damnit, another typo! As I said, I was going back and forth between the $.get and $.post, so I kept changing variables around. My bad

Comment: Where do you get the `$_get['id']` from? Like @PatBurke said, I dont think you should mix `post` with `get` http requests at the same time

Comment: @WebDeskIL $_get['id'] comes from when someone clicks on a comic thumbnail on the homepage, it's associated by ID to the full size of the image viewed on "viewimage.php" (see my website for example of how it works).  I agree with you, but I tried both the $.get and the $.post already, neither worked.

Comment: Have you tried `echo $_GET['id'];`?

Comment: @WebDeskIL Yes, that outputs what the original ID, and not updated id that is changed in the javascript when you hit a key

Comment: For debugging purposes, use the $_REQUEST[] scope with a generic variable name to test it out. This will encompass both $_GET and $_POST. See if it comes back then.

Comment: @PatBurke as such? KEYINPUT.PHP (JAVASCRIPT): $.post('./templates/viewimage.php', { _postID : imgIndex });   VIEWIMAGE.PHP: $newID = $_REQUEST['_postID'];  This doesn't work

Comment: @YoavKadosh any more thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem with your code is that you are using your Ajax code after the page has already loaded, while trying to change the `$_get` variables for the initial page load. AFAIK, you need to update the entire page for the "Facebook like" button to change it's ID. Another option would be to use an Iframe. From what I can see, the button's `data-href` attributes always leads to `http://hittingtreeswithsticks.com/` - and that can only be changed by reloading the page using a different attribute.

If you don't mind loading a page for each picture, this can work out for you:

```
<!-- This is the Like button code -->
<div [...] data-href="http://www.hittingtreeswithsticks.com/<?php echo $_get['id']; ?>"></div>
```

and the address for this page would be: `http://www.hittingtreeswithsticks.com/?id=PAGE_ID`

**EDIT**

Using AJAX, you are calling for data from the backend to be used in the client side, without having to reload the entire page. This data can then be used to alter the code in the client side. In your code, the data is being sent back to you but you are not using it at all, that's why it doesn't work:

```
$.get('./templates/viewimage.php', { _newImgId : imgIndex },
    function(data) {
        // This is where you should make use of the data received 
    }
);
```

**EDIT #2**

If you want to dynamically change the Like button's url, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764129/update-fblike-url-dynamically-using-javascript) answer.

Here is a fiddle of the working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/TkFma/4/

Comment: I thought the whole point of AJAX was to send a request to the server to update a certain portion of a loaded page- in this case that certain portion would be the server-side $imgid value.

Comment: So you're saying the only way to refresh the server-side $imgid is to refresh the page? And this is the only way that things like Facebook comments/likes will be updated with their associated ID?

Comment: @Growler You could also use an Iframe, having the "Like" button within it thus avoiding refreshing the entire page. See my update

Comment: According to JQuery4u.com, "A GET request is used to get data from the server. A POST request is used for modifying data on the server." So, if I change the request to $.post(), shouldn't I just be able to modify the data on the server (data being $imgid) without refreshing the page or using an iframe? (source: http://www.jquery4u.com/ajax/key-differences-post/)

Comment: @Growler Not really, but you can use ajax to change the Like button's url in the client side without refreshing the page or using an Iframe. see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764129/update-fblike-url-dynamically-using-javascript

Comment: I guess I can just put window.location.reload(); each time and have the page reload when someone hits a button... too bad I have to make it reload though :/ Edit: I noticed that the Facebook comments attached to an image ID are still not updating despite the page reloading

Comment: @Growler Have you looked at the link I have added? That might be what you're looking for

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24735/discussion-between-growler-and-yoav-kadosh)